# Solve the problem with Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability

I want to solve the following exercise:

John tells the truth two out of every three times he is asked, while Peter tells the truth four out of every five times. Both agree in assuring that from a box of marbles containing 6 marbles of different colors a red one was taken. Determine the probability that this statement is true.

So, consider:
A:John tells the truth

B:Peter tells the truth

C:A red marble comes out of the marble box.

I think our objective is to determine

$$P(E \mid A \cap B)=\frac{P(A \cap C \mid E) P(E)}{P(A \cap C)}$$

Thinking that $P(A)= \frac{2}{3}$, $P(B)= \frac{4}{5}$

And using the total probability theorem I could determine $P(A \cap C)$

I really don't see clearly how to perform the exercise approach, it is a bit confusing. Any help?

Comment: The question as stated is underdetermined. Are there only two colors of marbles? If so, how many of them are red? I don't believe it is possible to solve without knowing how many colors of marbles there are/what John and Peter say when they lie. Are you supposed to assume that John and Peter will say any color (uniformly) at random when they lie? Or will they follow some lying distribution?

Comment: The numbers of marbles or their colors appear irrelevant: the question is whether J&P both make the same assertion about an event they both observed.  The reason why the question is unanswerable, though, is that we don't know that J&P's assertions are *independent.*  For instance, maybe P tells the truth every time J does and also tell the truth sometimes when J is lying.  Perhaps this is what is causing you difficulties?  It's a legitimate reason to be concerned; but you might try to answer the question by assuming independence.

Comment: I think the standard way to interpret probabilistic liar puzzles is to imagine that whenever a probabilistic liar is about to answer a question, a (possibly biased) coin is flipped inside their mind, and they either lie or tell the truth according to the result of the flip. This was how Boolos clarified Smullyan and McCarthy's so-called "Hardest Logic Puzzle Ever". But other interpretations are certainly possible.